# Unit testing using ceedling

Tags: linux, pthreads, gcov, ceedling

i could not generate the coverage results of the source files. error is

Could not find coverage results for src/thr_func1.c
Could not find coverage results for src/thr_func2.c
Could not find coverage results for src/thr_func3.c

tried editing the path of project.yml

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.